# Amazon Web Services API- getting write access to read only files (Linux)

Tags: api, caching, amazon-web-services, permissions

I am very new to API programming. The software I am developing is using a Fuse-Driver , on a linux Virtual machine.

Under linux, there is a package called 'space dock' that encapsulates a lot of the API commands (GET , etc) required for accessing data.

What is happening is this:

When I run my application, I can view my files on the API, this API uses Amazon Web services and Amazon's electronic cloud computer.  I can only view them, I can not write them (read-only access).

When I end my process,  there is a created folder called 'bfs_cache' that gets saved onto my virtual machine.  This cache directory is only accessible when the program ends, and it turns out that the files have write-access under this cache'd directory.

The problem is that I am unable to figure out how to write the cache'd files into physical memory when the application is running.

I am reading this (see below) website, and it shows that private memory mapping page caches, that API's use, have read only permissions.  Yet this website does not explain how to switch the page cache to have shared memory mapping (which has write access).

http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/page-cache-the-affair-between-memory-and-files/

Using linux x86, is there a command that I can invoke that will search for a file in the cache and write it to physical memory?

Using an API, how can I change the read-only permissions using the AWS Rest API?

Note:  this 'space dock'  package automatically generates all the GET, and query commands used in an OAuth work flow.  This means I am not very good with the manual commands and would like to avoid a manual OAuth work flow.

Thank you very much, and if there is anything unclear please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved the "read only" access problem was to issue a 'cp' command into a directory that had write access.